# Can I add a knob that changes drawn lines on a matplotlib plot in a Labview style?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Say that I have a plot like this

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(-3, 3, 0.01)
j = 2
y = np.sin(np.pi*x*j)
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
line, = ax.plot(x, y)
plt.show()
```

is there anything in Matplotlib or more in general in Python in order to add something like a knob on the figure that changes the value of j and consequently the graph done in a Labview style?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is yes! The 'knob' is called `Slider` and you can use it to change parameters in the plot. See the [example at the matplotlib page](http://matplotlib.org/examples/widgets/slider_demo.html).

If this is not enough, you would need to create your own knob. Since Matplotlib can be integrated in GUIs like PyQt and Tkinter, this is quite easy but of course requires to be acquainted with those tools.

Answer (score 0):

Here I report a short code from the [link](http://matplotlib.org/examples/widgets/slider_demo.html) previously suggested:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import Slider

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.25, bottom=0.25)
t = np.arange(0.0, 1.0, 0.001)
a0 = 3
s = a0*np.sin(2*np.pi*t)
l, = plt.plot(t, s, lw=2, color='red')
plt.axis([0, 1, -10, 10])

axfreq = plt.axes([0.25, 0.1, 0.65, 0.03])

sfreq = Slider(axfreq, 'Freq', 0.1, 30.0, valinit=f0)


def update(val):
    freq = sfreq.val
    l.set_ydata(3*np.sin(2*np.pi*freq*t))
    fig.canvas.draw_idle()

sfreq.on_changed(update)
plt.show()
```

I believe this will make easier the life to who want to understand how Slider works